# Bottom left of Beamer Slide in LyX

Tags: beamer, lyx, lyx-layouts

Looking to fully customize the bottom left of all of my slides in LyX. I have three authors and it is trying to fit all of our full names while I want is "X et al. (Institution)" or just "X et al."

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Cambridge

\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\author{
LastName1, FirstName1\\
\texttt{first1.last1@xxxxx.com}
 \and
LastName2, FirstName2\\
\texttt{first2.last2@xxxxx.com}
LastName3, FirstName3\\
\texttt{first3.last3@xxxxx.com}
}

\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the so called "short" author: `\author[short version]{long version}` (see section 3.3 Title Material on the manual). I'm sure we have already at least one answer on this, but I can not find any now.

Comment: @Claudio Fiandrino Thanks, how is this incorporated in LyX? Also, how can I make the short author be my last name + et al?

Comment: Right click on the author --> Short author. Just write *Yourname et al*.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Perfect, this answers it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claudio provided the real answer -- using the 'short version' of the author, added as an optional argument to the `\author` command, i.e. `\author[short version]{long version}`. In LyX you can add this by right clicking the author and selecting *Short author*. 
In the box that show up, write your short version, e.g. `Yourname et al`.